# Depency injection not resolving inherited service (DbContext)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to registering one of two dbcontexts I have, based on a switch I pass that means if I want to seed the database or just run the service. So, I'm doing this on ConfigureServices:

```
//Add DB Service for application
bool seedDb = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("seeddb");

if(seedDb)
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbSeedDataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
else
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

The class hierarchy is really simple:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{ 
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbSeedDataContext : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbSeedDataContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options, new HttpContextAccessor())
    {
    }
}
```

Then I just expect in any method requesting an ApplicationDbContext that the DI system injects the one I instantiated, but it fails when I inject ApplicationDbSeedDataContext instead of ApplicationDbContext.

But I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service
>   descriptor 'ServiceType: WebAPI.Services.IUserService Lifetime: Scoped
>   ImplementationType: WebAPI.Services.UserService': Unable to resolve
>   service for type 'WebAPI.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext' while
>   attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Services.UserService'.

Userservice constructor is:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public UserService(IConfiguration configuration, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    ...
}
```

Shouldn't it be resolved correclty?

Comment: `ApplicationDbSeedDataContext` != `ApplicationDbContext`, why not inject both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbSeedDataContext>(...);
```

The container will not be aware of the base `ApplicationDbContext`

They will need to be registered as the same type.

Use the `AddDbContext` overload registration to explicitly specify the base type

```
//Add DB Service for application
bool seedDb = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("seeddb");

if(seedDb)
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbSeedDataContext>(options => ...);
else
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => ...);
```

That said, try to avoid injecting and using `IConfiguration` outside of `Startup` It really was not meant for that and can be seen as a code smell in most instances (SRP violation) consider using the Options Pattern

Comment: Exactly, just was testing this before you posted your solution. Did miss the different overloads. But I still can't make it work. I get this error:  System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: WebAPI.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: WebAPI.Contexts.ApplicationDbSeedDataContext': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[WebAPI.Contexts.ApplicationDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'WebAPI.Contexts.ApplicationDbSeedDataContext'. This time I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I just added them

Comment: Ok, Just fixed it. Too much time without having a rest. Thanks!

Comment: @Notbad glad you figured it out. Happy Coding